# JQuery go through several/all HTML elements with specific name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Basically I'd like my function to go through all HTML-elements with a specific name and compare each of their value's with a string.

I looked through Stackoverflow and other sites for a while, but nothing I found seemed to have worked. So far I tried:

```
function checkValue(name, value)
{
    $("[name=" + name + "]").each(function () {
        console.log(value);
    });
}
```

and

```
function checkValue(name, value)
{
    if ($("[name*=" + name + "]").val() == value) {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

But each gave an Error looking like this:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=[object HTMLInputElement]]
    at Function.oe.error (jquery.min.js:2)
    at oe.tokenize (jquery.min.js:2)
    at oe.select (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Function.oe [as find] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.find (jquery.min.js:2)
    at new w.fn.init (jquery.min.js:2)
    at w (jquery.min.js:2)
    at checkValue (index.js:10)
    at include_moduleingabe_function.php:280
```

EDIT:

Turns out I had both in my code and my function-call some quotation marks missing, which messed it all up.
I changed the code to:

```
function checkValue(name, value)
{
    if ($("[name='" + name + "']").val() == value) {
        console.log(value);
    }
}
```

This variant doesn't throw an error anymore, though it doesn't seem to be checking each element with that `name` attribute, but only the first...

Comment: Try `$("[name='" + name + "']")` as per https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Comment: The error is clear: `name=[object HTMLInputElement]` is not a valid expression. `name` is not the name of the input element but the element itself

Comment: Make sure you are passing a string as `name`

Comment: @Andreas you are correct! Turns out I had some quotation marks missing in my function call, which messed the `name` parameter up. Thank you for explaining that!

Comment: @ClydeLobo Thank you, that worked!

Comment: @ClydeLobo Nevermind, you were right with the quotationmarks missing, though it doesn't seem to be going through every element and only the first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the attribute starts with, something like this:

```
var StartsWith;
StartsWith = 'txt';
$('[id^=' + StartsWith + ']').each(function () {
    if (this.value == 'myStringToCompare') {
        alert(this.id);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've changed my example to clarify it a little bit more. Hope it helps now.

Comment: I've changed it a bit to still look after the name rather than the id, but using `this` finally made it work for me, thank you!